# Grainy/Pixelated UIImage drawn in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage, interface-builder, draw

[image]

Thats my issue basically. On my iOS device i see the icons this grainy. The imageView is 35px. The icon is drawn with the code below. I cant understand why does aspectFit make this icon look so bad? I also tries adding simple image assets and even then it looked the same. Any idea whats wrong?

```
func drawSocialfacebookoutline(frame targetFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 512, height: 512), resizing: ResizingBehavior = .aspectFit) {
    //// General Declarations
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    //// Resize to Target Frame
    context.saveGState()
    let resizedFrame: CGRect = resizing.apply(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 512, height: 512), target: targetFrame)
    context.translateBy(x: resizedFrame.minX, y: resizedFrame.minY)
    context.scaleBy(x: resizedFrame.width / 512, y: resizedFrame.height / 512)


    //// Bezier Drawing
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 288, y: 192))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 288, y: 153.9))
    bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 318.5, y: 128), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 288, y: 136.7), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 291.8, y: 128))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 352, y: 128))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 352, y: 64))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 296.1, y: 64))
    bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 205, y: 149.3), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 227.6, y: 64), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 205, y: 95.4))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 205, y: 192))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 160, y: 192))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 160, y: 256))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 205, y: 256))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 205, y: 448))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 288, y: 448))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 288, y: 256))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 344.4, y: 256))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 352, y: 192))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 288, y: 192))
    bezierPath.close()
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 330.2, y: 240))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 289.1, y: 240))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 272, y: 240))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 272, y: 255.5))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 272, y: 432))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 221, y: 432))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 221, y: 255.5))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 221, y: 240))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 206.1, y: 240))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 176, y: 240))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 176, y: 208))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 206.1, y: 208))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 221, y: 208))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 221, y: 191.5))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 221, y: 149.3))
    bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 236.5, y: 97.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 221, y: 124.8), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 226.4, y: 108.1))
    bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 296.1, y: 80), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 247.7, y: 85.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 267.6, y: 80))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 336, y: 80))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 336, y: 112))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 318.5, y: 112))
    bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 281.4, y: 123.7), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 306.5, y: 112), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 291, y: 113.1))
    bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 272, y: 153.8), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 273.3, y: 132.7), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 272, y: 143.8))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 272, y: 191.4))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 272, y: 208))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 289.1, y: 208))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 334, y: 208))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 330.2, y: 240))
    bezierPath.close()
    DKStyleKit.dkBlue.setFill()
    bezierPath.fill()

    context.restoreGState()

}
```

Then here is the conversion of the draw method to UIImage:

```
public dynamic class var imageOfSocialfacebookoutline: UIImage {
    if Cache.imageOfSocialfacebookoutline != nil {
        return Cache.imageOfSocialfacebookoutline!
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 512, height: 512), false, 0)
        DKStyleKit.drawSocialfacebookoutline()

    Cache.imageOfSocialfacebookoutline = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return Cache.imageOfSocialfacebookoutline!
}
```

Any hints or solutions are welcome.